# JavaFX TableView editable(true) don't work

Tags: java, javafx

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] ar){ launch(ar); }

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    TableView<Foo> tableView = new TableView<>();
    tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    tableView.setPlaceholder(new Label("No data"));
    tableView.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn<Foo, String> colText = new TableColumn<>("Text");
    colText.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));

    tableView.getColumns().add(colText);

    List<Foo> listFoo = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Foo("1"), new Foo("2"), new Foo("3")));

    tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(listFoo));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
    primaryStage.show();

}

public class Foo{

    private String text;

    public Foo(String txt){ text = txt; }

    public String getText(){ return text; }

    public void setText(String text){ this.text = text; }

}
```

I try to make the cells of table editable: `tableView.setEditable(true);`, but it don't work.

How can I make cells of table editable or to have posibility to copy the value from cell into clipboard.

Comment: Please include the code for the Foo class.  You need to define your properties in that class according to Java bean and JavaFX conventions:  `getText()`, `setText(int)`, and if possible, `textProperty()`.

Comment: @VGR Done. I forgot about Foo class. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a `TableCell` to be editable, 3 conditions need to be fulfilled:

1. The containing `TableView` is editable
2. The containing `TableColumn` is editable
3. The cell itself is editable

In your case the 3rd condition is not fulfilled, since the cells created by the default `cellFactory` are not editable. You need to assign a `cellFactory` that allows for editing. Furthermore note that unless the `cellValueFactory` returns an object implementing `WritableValue`, you also need to use the `onEditCommit` handler to store the data in the item:

```
colText.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
colText.setOnEditCommit(evt -> evt.getRowValue().setText(evt.getNewValue()));
```

Comment: How I can do this for other type of content than String?

Comment: @KunLun There are other subclasses of `TableCell` that work for different value types. Of course you could also create your own implementation. If you want to use a `TextField` to input the data, you can pass a `StringConverter` to [the overloaded version of the `forTableColumn` method](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn(javafx.util.StringConverter)).